# Jitsi: Unable to change default user avatar

Tags: reactjs, mern, jitsi, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

I have integrated Jetsi directly in my React app using the API (Without a self-hosted server).
I have been trying to find a way to change the default avatar when the user camera is off.

According to the [documentation](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-configuration/#gravatar), I can override this parameter:

```
gravatar: {
    baseUrl: 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/',
    disabled: false
}
```

> baseUrl  - Base URL for a Gravatar-compatible service. Defaults to
> Gravatar. disabled - True if Gravatar should be disabled.

I tried overriding it in both `configOverwrite` and `interfaceConfigOverwrite`:

```
   <Jutsu
          roomName={room_name}
          configOverwrite={{
            gravatar: {
              baseUrl:
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4d/Cat_November_2010-1a.jpg/1200px-Cat_November_2010-1a.jpg",
              disabled: false,
            },
          }}
          interfaceConfigOverwrite={{
            gravatar: {
              baseUrl:
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4d/Cat_November_2010-1a.jpg/1200px-Cat_November_2010-1a.jpg",
              disabled: false,
            },
          }}
        />
```

But, it had no effect.

I don't even understand what they mean by

> Gravatar-compatible service

Can't I just use an image url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a note at the beginning of the docs, the `gravatar.baseUrl` option can't be overwritten

> NOTE
> Options marked with  are not overwritable through configOverwrite

You'll need to set it in the `config.js` [file](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/config.js) of your jitsi installation.

And the baseUrl should be a service that works the same as gravatar: receiving a hashed email and returning an image; no other option is [supported](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/issues/5254#issuecomment-1008265690). You can check how the URL is built here https://github.com/jitsi/js-utils/blob/master/avatar/index.js#L10

You could use an out of the box alternative as https://wiki.libravatar.org/ or build your own https://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_build_an_enhanced_gravatar_service_part_1